# Running Compiz using Optirun?

Tags: compiz, bumblebee

I have an Optimus laptop. I have Ironhide installed, and can use optirun to run programs using the discrete GPU from the command line. However, is there any way to run Compiz itself on the discrete GPU?

Comment: Have you tried `compiz --replace` with optirun?

Comment: Do you have and updated Bumblebee? See: https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/621

Comment: Here is a more recent thread where people claimed success: http://askubuntu.com/questions/126795/enable-hardware-accelerated-desktop-effects-with-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee

Answer (score 2):

At present with the current version of Bumblebee (3.0) this is not possible. Running `optirun compiz --replace` results in a segmentation fault. This would be a topic to bring up on the Bumblebee forums. However, running compiz using the accelerated graphics completely ruins the whole point of Bumblebee, which is to only run applications which require more graphics capabilities on the better GPU, therefore saving battery life. Running compiz, a process which runs all the time, on the higher power consumption GPU would cause a significant loss of battery life. So, while you may be able to accomplish this by asking at the Bumblebee forums, you are circumventing the whole point of having Bumblebee.

Comment: If `optirum compiz --replace` segfaults, perhaps that crash should be [reported as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) (with a stack trace and other technical information). Do you know if such a bug has been reported?