# Stuck at Unity2D, Intel video borked, discrete NVidia seems to work (Bumblebee set up)

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I've been stuck with Unity 2D all day at 1024x768, tried all sorts of workarounds to no avail. My issues started when I upgraded to mesa9.0 in the `ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates` PPA. After a reboot, I was kicked in Unity2D and couldn't get 3D to work again. I downgraded all packages manually to 8.0.4 hoping this would solve the issue, but it didn't. I've been through all topics on AskUbuntu and Ubuntu Forums, followed all advise I could find and still nothing. My system seems to be in a state of flux which I can't get out of.

**TL;DR; SOLUTION**

After struggling for hours on end on this one, I finally stumbled upon a bug report for CentOS where someone was having similar issues. It turns out that during an `apt-get upgrade`, a package (I really cannot tell which) added `nomodeset` as as option to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`. Once that was removed (oddly there was a `vga=1` as well, got rid of that too), the Intel drivers work as expected again.

I will attempt another upgrade to Mesa 9 over the weekend, hopefully it won't lead me straight back to this thread.

---

I tried pretty much everything I could find:

```
$ _ apt-get purge 'bumblebee*' 'nvidia-current*' 'nvidia-settings*'
$ _ reboot
$ _ apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libgles1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libopenvg1-mesa libegl1-mesa libosmesa6:i386 libosmesa6 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 xserver-xorg-core libdrm-dev libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-intel1 libkms1 libgbm1 --reinstall
$ _ reboot
$ _ rm -f /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so* /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia_drv.so
$ _ reboot
$ _ rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
$ _ reboot
$ _ apt-get install bumblebee
```

So essentially, I purged everything, re-installed everything and still nothing.

I followed the advise in [Enable hardware-accelerated desktop effects with NVIDIA Optimus/Bumblebee](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126795/enable-hardware-accelerated-desktop-effects-with-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee):

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules
```

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 53 Oct 18 17:58 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules -> /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules
    $ ls -l /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 48 Oct 18 17:58 /etc/alternatives/x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules
    $ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules
total 0

---

```
$ uname -a
Linux stan-inspiron 3.2.0-32-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 26 21:33:09 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ $ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=12.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=precise
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS"
```

---

```
$ update-alternatives --display x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf - manual mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf
/usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf - priority 9700
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_grub_fb_blacklist: /usr/share/nvidia-current/nvidia-current.grub-gfxpayload
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libOpenCL.so: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libOpenCL.so_lib32: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/libOpenCL.so
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libvdpau_nvidia.so: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libvdpau_nvidia.so.1: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libvdpau_nvidia.so.1_lib32: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so.1
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_libvdpau_nvidia.so_lib32: /usr/lib32/nvidia-current/vdpau/libvdpau_nvidia.so
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_man_nvidiaxconfig.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-current-xconfig.1.gz
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-autostart.desktop: /usr/share/nvidia-current/nvidia-autostart.desktop
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia-smi.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/alt-nvidia-current-smi.1.gz
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia.icd: /usr/share/nvidia-current/nvidia.icd
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_bug_report: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/bin/nvidia-bug-report.sh
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_desktop: /usr/share/nvidia-current/ubuntu-nvidia-settings.desktop
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_drv: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/nvidia_drv.so
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_modconf: /lib/nvidia-current/modprobe.conf
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_smi: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/bin/nvidia-smi
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_nvidia_xconfig: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/bin/nvidia-xconfig
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_xvmcconfig: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/XvMCConfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/ld.so.conf - priority 500
  slave x86_64-linux-gnu_xorg_extra_modules: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/x11-extra-modules
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/nvidia-current/ld.so.conf'.
```

---

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable     
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/stan/.drirc: No such file or directory.
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 8.0.4

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

---

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'                          
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] [10de:0df5] (rev ff) (prog-if ff)
```

---

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose optirun /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p 
OpenGL vendor string:   NVIDIA Corporation        
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GT 525M/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL version string:  4.2.0 NVIDIA 304.51

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  no
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

---

My thinking is that Bumblebee is working as expected, however I am not able to make use of the Intel video and it fallbacks to VESA.

Could anyone shed any light and possibly help me?

For fullness, [here is the Xorg.0.log file](https://gist.github.com/3544a5d1aa02b93e0774).

**EDIT 1**: I restored a back-up of my `/etc` directory from before the upgrade and compared all files againt their current version. There are no changes in any of the files in `/etc/X11` so it leads me to think again it must be some library stuck somewhere causing mayhem.

**EDIT 2**: As suggested, `xserver-xorg-core` was re-installed:

```
$ dpkg -S libglx.so
  nvidia-current: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so
  nvidia-current: /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so.304.51
  xserver-xorg-core: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
$ _ apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree
  Reading state information... Done
  0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
  Need to get 0 B/1,719 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
  (Reading database ... 342599 files and directories currently installed.)
  Preparing to replace xserver-xorg-core 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8 (using .../xserver-xorg-core_2%3a1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8_amd64.deb) ...
  Unpacking replacement xserver-xorg-core ...
  Processing triggers for man-db ...
  Setting up xserver-xorg-core (2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.8) ...
  localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/locale: 0 KiB
  localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/man: 0 KiB
  localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/gnome/help: 0 KiB
  localepurge: Disk space freed in /usr/share/omf: 0 KiB
  Total disk space freed by localepurge: 0 KiB
$ _ reboot
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxgears
  libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
  libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
  libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
  libGL: Can't open configuration file /etc/drirc: No such file or directory.
  libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/stan/.drirc: No such file or directory.
  8434 frames in 5.0 seconds = 1686.685 FPS
  XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server ":0"
        after 31148 requests (31148 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
$ _ updatedb
$ locate libglx.so
  /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so
  /usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg/libglx.so.304.51
  /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
```

Log files and issue experienced remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-dev mesa-common-dev libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx libglapi-mesa libglapi-mesa:i386 libgles2-mesa libgles1-mesa libegl1-mesa-drivers libopenvg1-mesa libegl1-mesa libosmesa6:i386 libosmesa6 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 xserver-xorg-core libdrm-dev libdrm2 libdrm2:i386 libdrm-radeon1 libdrm-radeon1:i386 libdrm-nouveau1a libdrm-nouveau1a:i386 libdrm-intel1:i386 libdrm-intel1 libkms1 libgbm1 --reinstall
$ reboot
$ rm -f /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so* /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia_drv.so
```

This sequence is wrong, you reinstalled a package providing libglx.so and removed that file again. Use http://packages.ubuntu.com/ (or `dpkg -S libglx.so`) to find which package provides that file. Then reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, it's a tough one this one. I think I tried your approach as well, but I repeated it just in case. See **EDIT 2** above.

Comment: I believe I've done something horrible and Intel video won't even start. The logs are not very helpful. I even tried `startx` with extreme verbosity, but that didn't yield anything good. I wish there was a way to debug why the Intel libraries are not being loaded.

When I tried to force X to load just the `intel` driver in `xorg.conf`, I got a corrupted system so back to VESA for now.